# Ругается на конкатенацию std::string and const char *

Tags: c++, строки

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

const char* IntParse(int _int)
{
  string str_s("");

  while(_int / 10 > 0)
  {
    str_s.insert(0, "" + _int % 10 + 48);
    _int /= 10;
  }

  return str_s.c_str();
}

class Button
{
  string id;
  static uint count;
  static const string buttonWord;

public:

  Button(void (*_Maker) () ) : 
    id( buttonWord + IntParse( count++ ) ),
    down(false),
    Maker(_Maker)
  {
    cout << id.c_str() << "\n";
  };

  Button(const string &_id, void (*_Maker) ()) : 
    id(_id),
    down(false),
    Maker(_Maker)
  {
    cout << id.c_str() << "\n";
  };

  ~Button() { };

  bool down;

  void (*Maker) ();
};
```

Ошибка конкатенации в конструкторе класса `Button`, при инициализации `id`

Comment: `"" + _int % 10 + 48` Как вы думаете, что делает этот код?

Comment: Обратил внимание, что часто начинающий народ использует `using namespace std` - и кто вас только этому учит. Если вы считаете что это улучшает читаемость кода, то вы глубоко заблуждаетесь.

Comment: @Cerbo, что не так с `using namespace std`?

Comment: а нужно всегда писать `std::`, @ixSci

Comment: @ixSci а то, что имена классов STL слишком "востребованные"  и поэтому без `std::` непонятно что имеется в виду. Самый, в этом смысле, проблемный `string`. Например, для сабжевого кода, я только из контекста убедился что речь идет об эстэлевском классе. Хотя да, тема холиварная.

Comment: @Cerbo, так можно сказать про любой язык, но я не видел ни одного человек, кто бы сказал `using System;` это холиварная тема для C#. Нет, все просто пишут `using System;` и не морочат себе голову. Я вообще не понимаю, откуда берутся эти "запреты" на `using namespace std` в cpp файлах. Они ни на чём не основаны.

Comment: neitron, не для учебных заданий, а для будущего (надеюсь) -- гляньте `man sprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего это очень плохая идея использовать имена переменных, которые за исключением одного ведущего подчеркивания совпадают с именами типов, как имя  переменной `_int`. Тем самым вы только затрудняете чтение своих программ и создаете условия для потенциальных ошибок.

Функция `IntParse` написана некорректно. В следующем предложении функции

```
str_s.insert(0, "" + _int % 10 + 48);
```

в выражении `"" + _int % 10 + 48` происходит не конкатенация строкового литерала и целочисленного значения, а арифметика указателей, которая к адресу первого символа строкового литерала `""` прибавляет значение равное
`_int % 10 + 48`. В результате полученный указатель будет указывать на некоторую область памяти, которая вам не принадлежит. Поэтому программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Кроме того вы возвращаете из функции указатель на временный объект

```
return str_s.c_str();
```

который будет удален по завершению работы функции. Следовательно имеется еще одна причина неопределенного поведения программы.

Условие этого цикла также неверное, так как оно игнорирует числа, состоящие из одной цифры, как, например, 8 или 9.

```
  while(_int / 10 > 0)
  {
    str_s.insert(0, "" + _int % 10 + 48);
    _int /= 10;
  }
```

Также непонятно, почему вы используете параметр с типом `int`, хотя отрицательные значения для этого параметра, насколько я полагаю, не предполагается использовать, так как вы в качестве аргумента функции передаете статический член данных `count`, имеющий тип `uint`

```
uint count;
```

Функция может быть написана просто

```
std::string IntParse( unsigned int n )
{
    return std::to_string( n );
}
```

Ежели вы по какой-то причине не можете использовать эту функцию, то ее определение может выглядеть следующим образом

```
std::string IntParse( unsigned int n )
{
    std::string s;
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    do
    {
        s += n % Base + '0';
    } while ( n /= Base );

    return std::string( s.rbegin(), s.rend() );
}
```

Comment: (1) `s/кeturn/return/`, (2) `IntParse` — не совсем хорошее имя для функции, которая превращает не _из_ строки, а _в_ строку, (3) а зачем копировать строку на выходе (`std::string( s.rbegin(), s.rend() )`)?

Comment: @VladD Возвращается реверсная строка. Конечно вы могли бы применить алгоритм std:;reverse и возвращать ту же самую строку с использованием std::move, но я не думаю, что следует перегружать автора вопроса темами, которые ему неизвестны.

Comment: А, понял, не заметил `r` в `rbegin`.

Comment: @VladD, с стд я знаком так что не переживайте, спасибо за развернутый ответ, но ведь вопрос был в другом) и да, зачем реверсировать строку, если можно сразу помещать символ перед нулевым элементом.

Comment: @neitron Когда вы помещаете каждый новый символ в начало строки, то каждый раз происходит сдвиг строки посредством ее копирования. Чтобы избежать этого, проще добавлять символы в конец строки, а затем возвратить строку в обратном порядке следования ее символов.

Comment: @neitron Что касается вашего исходного вопроса, то каждый отвечающий видит лишь тот код, который вы привели в своем вопросе.  Мы не можем гадать, например, включили ли вы какой-нибудь заголовок или нет, если вы не показываете программу целиком, а лишь отдельные ее части.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, спасибо огромное, а можно еще такой вопрос, как вы предпологали возвращать аргумент через std::move, return std::move(str_s), и какие преимущества?

Comment: @neitron Так как это локальная переменная то компилятор применит оптимизацию возвращаемого значения, так называемую RVO. Поэтому нет большего смысла использовать std::move. Компилятор построит объект сразу же в принимающем возвращающее значение объекте.

Comment: @neitron, использование `std::move` на возвращаемом значении это в 99.99% случаев неправильно. Во-первых, возвращаемое из функции значение и так будет перемещено, если есть конструктор перемещения, во-вторых: `std::move` отменяет (N)RVO оптимизацию.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в функции `const char* IntParse(int _int)`. Она создаёт временную строку `str_s`, берёт её буфер, и возвращает из функции, разрушая при этом исходную строку. То есть на момент выхода из функции буфер `str_s` уже разрушен. Как вы думаете, можно ли теперь пользоваться возвращённой сишной строкой? Нельзя, это UB.

Если вы уж пишете на C++, пользуйтесь его управлением памятью, чтобы не делать ошибок.

Чтобы не заниматься сложным ручным управлением памятью, **всегда** пользуйтесь идиоматическими строками C++.

```
string itos(int _int)
{
  string str_s;
  if (_int < 0)
  {
      str_s = "-";
      _int = -_int; // TODO: случай MININT?
  }
  if (_int == 0)
      str_s = "0";

  while (_int > 0)
  {
    str_s = (char)(_int % 10 + '0') + str_s;
    _int /= 10;
  }

  return str_s;
}
```

Теперь ваш код работает без проблем:

```
Button(void (*maker) () ) : 
  id( buttonWord + itos( count++ ) ),
  down(false),
  Maker(maker)
{
  cout << id << "\n";
};
```

---

Если вы работаете с C++11 или новее, вы можете не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться готовым [`std::to_string(int)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

При использовании C++11 у вас даже не будет затрат на копирование `str_s` при выходе из `itos` из-за [семантики переноса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#.D0.A1.D1.81.D1.8B.D0.BB.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.8A.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.8B_.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.B0_.28Rvalue_Reference.2FMove_semantics.29), но не думайте об этом покамест: первоочерёдной задачей является корректность, а потом уж эффективность.

Answer (score -1):

проблема была в том, что я не подключил заголовочный файл

Comment: Вы всё же прочитайте остальные ответы и поймите, почему функция `IntParse` никуда не годится.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо)