# Перевод из десятичной в двоичную систему счисления C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте товарищи знатоки!
Написал такую программу которая переводит десятичные числа в двоичные. Но есть одно НО.
Работает она правильно только с некоторыми числами. Например если ввести 12 или 36
С другими очень криво.
Например:

- Ответ 100 выводится при числах от 4 до 7
- Ответ 0100 выводится от 8 до 11
- Ответ 1100 выводится от 12 до 15
- Ответ 00100 выводится от 16 до 19
- Ответ 10100 выводится от 20 до 23
- Ответ 01100 выводится от 24 до 27
- Ответ 11100 выводится от 28 до 31
- Ответ 000100 выводится от 32 до 35
- Ответ 100100 выводится от 36 до 39

Дальше ответ идет 010100 от 40 и т.д.

Сам не могу разобраться так как задали мне работу с телефонами. По этому прошу Вашей помощи.
Вот собственно код:
(Он очень примитивный)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num=0, t=0;
    cout<<"Enter count:"<<endl;
    cout<<"==> ";
    cin>>num;
    while(num)
    {
        num=num/2;
        t=num%2;
        cout<<t;
    }
    cout<<num;
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9):

Вы делаете неправильно. Вы пытаетесь построить такое *число*, чтобы если его вывести как десятичное, получилось двоичное представление числа.

Это не правильно, так делать не надо, это лишь приведёт к проблемам. Нужно различать само число (переменную числового типа) и его представление в той или иной системе счисления (строку).

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <string>

std::string to_binary_string(unsigned int n)
{
    std::string buffer; // символы ответа в обратном порядке
    // выделим память заранее по максимуму
    buffer.reserve(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits);
    do
    {
        buffer += char('0' + n % 2); // добавляем в конец
        n = n / 2;
    } while (n > 0);
    return std::string(buffer.crbegin(), buffer.crend()); // разворачиваем результат
}
```

Для случая, когда вам нужно обрабатывать и отрицательные числа, нужна небольшая модификация:

```
#include <string>
#include <limits>

std::string to_binary_string(int n)
{
    if (n == std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
        return "-1" + std::string(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits, '0');
    std::string buffer;
    buffer.reserve(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits + 1); // +1 для минуса
    bool negative = (n < 0);
    if (negative)
        n = -n;
    do
    {
        buffer += char('0' + n % 2);
        n = n / 2;
    } while (n > 0);
    if (negative)
        buffer += '-';
    return std::string(buffer.crbegin(), buffer.crend());
}
```

Это решение естественно обобщается на произвольный тип:

```
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
std::string to_binary_string(T n)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Integer required.");
    if (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed &&
        n == std::numeric_limits<T>::min()) // (*)
    {
        // переполнение в знаковом типе - UB, избегаем его
        return "-1" + std::string(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits, '0');
    }

    std::string buffer;
    buffer.reserve(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits + 1); // +1 для возможного минуса

    bool negative = (n < 0);
    if (negative)
        n = -n; // это можно делать вследствие проверки (*)

    do
    {
        buffer += char('0' + n % 2);
        n = n / 2;
    } while (n > 0);

    if (negative)
        buffer += '-';

    return std::string(buffer.crbegin(), buffer.crend());
}
```

(Код частично украден из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431384/10105).)

---

Величина `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` представляет количество бит в знаковом целочисленном типе, участвующих в представлении значения (без учёта знакового бита и битов заполнения (*padding bits*)), соответственно даёт количество двоичных цифр в самой длинной строке (за исключиением отрицательного минимума).

Comment: да вы правы, есть очень много вариантов. человек выбрал это.

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev: Мне кажется, что число, которое будучи выведенным как десятичное будет выглядеть, как двоичное представление другого числа, имеет достаточно слабую семантику. Кроме того, с строкой можно представить как угодно большие числа, а вот число 255 в двоичном виде будет 11111111 и не поместится в один байт в предлагаемой схеме.

Comment: согласен вы правы

Comment: @wololo: спасибо, с вашими правками вышло изящнее

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы отрезаете последнее значение при  `num=num/2;`

   Это должно быть в конце цикла.
2. Значения нужно выводить в обратном порядке.

---

Вот изменил код. Проверьте.

тут `d` это разряд. Потому что нужно обратно все печатать.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num=0, t=0, d=1;
    cout<<"Enter count:"<<endl;
    cout<<"==> ";
    cin>>num;
    while(num)
    {
        t +=(num%2)*d;
        //cout<<t;
        num=num/2;
        d=d*10; // razryad
    }
    cout<<t;
  //  cout<<num;
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы имели в виду это? 
`while(num)
{
t=num%2;
cout<<t;
num=num/2;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
int a;
int tmp = 1;
std::cin >> a;
if (a < 0) {
    a *= -1;
    std::cout << '-';
}

if (a == 0) std::cout << 0;
else {
    
while (tmp <= a) tmp = tmp << 1;

while (tmp > 1) {
    tmp = tmp >> 1;
    std::cout << (((tmp & a) != 0) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Вот 2 функции, которые я когда-то давно писал.

Первая функция переводит из 10-ой системы счисления целые числа в любую другую систему счисления от 2 до 36.

```
std::string TransferDecimalToAny(long long int number, const unsigned int &base)
{
    const char *DIGITS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    bool FlagInverse = false;
    std::string reversString, stringInBase;

    if (base < 2 || base > 36)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: основание должно быть от 2 до 36." << std::endl;
        return "-1";
    }
    if (number < 0)
    {
        FlagInverse = true;
        number *= -1;
    }

    stringInBase += DIGITS[number % base];
    number = number / base;
    while (number)
    {
        stringInBase += DIGITS[number % base];
        number = number / base;
    }

    if (FlagInverse == true)
        reversString = "-";

    for (int i = stringInBase.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        reversString += stringInBase[i];

    return reversString;
}
```

А вторая функция также переводит из 10-ой системы счисления в любую другую систему счисления от 2 до 36, но только уже дробные числа причем с заданной точностью *accuracy*.

```
std::string TransferDecimalToAny(long double number, const unsigned int &base, const int &accuracy)
{
    const char *DIGITS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int iter = 0, tmp = 0;
    bool FlagInverse = false;

    if (number < 0)
    {
        FlagInverse = true;
        number *= -1;
    }
    long long int integer;
    long double integer_tmp, fractional;
    std::string reversString, stringInBase;
    if (base < 2 || base > 36)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: основание должно быть от 2 до 36." << std::endl;
        return "-1";
    }

    fractional = modf(number, &integer_tmp);
    integer = static_cast<long long int>(integer_tmp);

    stringInBase += DIGITS[integer % base];
    integer = integer / base;
    while (integer)
    {
        stringInBase += DIGITS[integer % base];
        integer = integer / base;
    }

    if (FlagInverse == true)
        reversString = "-";

    for (int i = stringInBase.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        reversString += stringInBase[i];
    reversString += '.';

    while (iter < accuracy)
    {
        fractional *= base;
        fractional = modf(fractional, &integer_tmp);
        tmp = static_cast<int>(integer_tmp);
        reversString += DIGITS[tmp];
        iter++;
    }

    return reversString;
}
```

А вызывать их соответственно следующим образом:

```
long long int number1 = -54605429;
long double number2 = -6546747.63768658;
std::cout << "Введите основание перевода: ";
std::cin >> base;

std::cout << "Перевод целого: " << TransferDecimalToAny(number1, base).c_str() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Перевод дробного: " << TransferDecimalToAny(number2, base, 13).c_str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Для LLONG_MIN неправильно будет работать (это значение надо отдельно обрабатывать, можете [посмотреть](http://pastebin.com/zaNt0Y8C) как).

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант без делений.

```
#include <iostream>


char* dec_to_bin(char* s, int n){
   unsigned int u = (unsigned int)n;
   char* t = s;

   do {
       *s++ = (char)((u & 1) + '0');
   } while((u >>= 1) != 0);
   *s-- = '\0';

   char c;
   for(char* p = t; p < s; ++p, --s){
       c  = *p;
       *p = *s;
       *s = c;
   }
   return t;
}


int main(void){
    char buf[(sizeof(int) << 3) + 1];

    std::cout << dec_to_bin(buf,  2012) << std::endl;
    std::cout << dec_to_bin(buf, -2012) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x, a;
    cin >> a;
    for (int i =31; i>=0; i--)
    {
        x = ((a >> i) & 1);
        cout << x << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов алгоритма конечно много, но я так понимаю вопрос почему не работает.

Принципиальная ошибка в цикле: надо сначала получить остаток от деления, а потом собственно делить.

Правда вывод все равно в обратном порядке. Нужно добавлять буфер.

```
while(num)
{ 
    //num=num/2; // удалить
    t=num%2;
    num=num/2; // переместить сюду
    cout<<t;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Вот код на C++ для перевода с десятичной в двоичную систему. Писал сам, ибо ответа в интернете так и не нашол. Код насколько ето возможно простой. Писал отдельной функцией.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void function(int a) {
long long int n = 0;
int k,m = 0;
while(a) {
    k = a % 2;
    a = a / 2;
    n += k * pow(10, m);
    m++;
}
cout << n << endl;
}

int main()
{
int a;
cin >> a;
function(a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы делаете перевод не в строку, а в int32. int32 и правда может хранить в десятичном представлении до 8 штук едениц, но не более, поэтому int обычно не используют.

Answer (score -4):

реализация с использованием побитового сдвига.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void to_binar(int a, string &s)
{
    int mx = 0;
    while ((a >> mx++) > 1);
    int num = a, bin;
    while (mx > 0)
    {
        bin = pow(2, --mx);
        if (num < bin)
            s += '0';
        else
        {
            s += '1';
            num -= bin;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a1 = 77, a2 = 76;
    string s1, s2;
    to_binar(a1, s1);
    to_binar(a2, s2);
    cout << s1 << endl << s2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основан ваш код?